# How to access method in Java from Javascript in html?

Tags: java, javascript, html

I've been learning about web programming, and I am currently stuck on getting a method coded on the server client(in Java) to run when I click a button on webpage(in html and javascript).

Basically, I created a Java server client where upon running, I can go to web browser and type "localhost:8080/index.html" and the page will show up with buttons and some buttons have javascript attached to it so that I can click and interact.

However, I have one method in Java which I want Javascript to access it when I click a button. How do I do that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: is the Java method currently exposed in a webservice?

Comment: @MStodd By that, do you mean using tomcat/jetty/servlets? No I am trying to avoid those at all cost.

Comment: What you are looking for is likely a [HTML Form](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/forms.php), which would send data entered on the client (the browser) to the web server (the Java). Java can then interact with the data and send a response back to the client. Understand there is a separation between the client and the server and limits on how they can interact.

Comment: @js0823 You're avoiding the only mechanism that can make this possible?  You want Java code to run on the server, but not exposing it via webservice?  See Deleteman's answer.  Start by getting a minimal webservice working, then try hitting it with really basic AJAX using jQuery or something

Comment: What do you mean with a "server client"? Is it an applet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't take this the wrong way, but the question alone shows that you still have to do a lot of reading about web development.

Since you're working with Java I would recommend googling for "java web development tutorial" or stuff like that.

Here are a couple of links to get you started:

http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/

http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-tutorials/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for those links. I've actually read one of them, not thoroughly though. Anyway, from what I understand, javascript is a client side language and I should be using JSP to create a dynamic webpage. I am however looking for a way to not use tomcat/jetty/servlets in anyway if possible.

Comment: If you want dynamic websites and you want to have part of the logic on the server side, you need to use one of those technologies if you're using Java. There are others, that might be easier for someone who's just starting out, like PHP, or Rails, but if you're going with Java, I don't think you have other options.